# Configure Cisco router overload NAT (IOS 15)

Tags: cisco, router, nat

I am attempting to configure a Cisco 2901 router using IOS 15 to properly perform NAT/PAT translation between LAN and the internet connection. I've configured DHCP pool for the local interface, which works properly (even using an additional switch, wireless access point, ...). Likewise, the WAN interface is configured to obtain its own IP by DHCP from the ISP. I can work on the LAN computers and I can access the internet directly from the router (using, for example, telnet and router's ping commands).
The problem is, NAT does not work properly and connection from the LAN interface (GigabitEthernet0/1) does not reach the WAN interface (GigabitEthernet0/0).

I have followed several [guides](http://www.itsyourip.com/cisco/how-to-configure-nat-in-cisco-ios-nat-overload/) on the matter, but it seems that no matter what I do, NAT just doesn't seem to work. I have tried both the `interface GigabitEthernet0/0 overload` NAT inside source list and the NAT pool source list (being the current ISP-assigned IP) described in the guides.

Attached is the complete configuration, hoping someone finds the problem I have missed.

```
Current configuration : 2007 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 19:59:30 UTC Wed Jul 6 2011
!
version 15.0
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname odin
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable secret 5 enablesecret
enable password enablepassword
!
no aaa new-model
!
!
!
!
no ipv6 cef
ip source-route
no ip routing
no ip cef
!
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.1.1.1 10.1.1.10
!
ip dhcp pool lan
   import all
   network 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 10.1.1.1
   dns-server 8.8.8.8
!
!
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
voice-card 0
!
!
!
!
!
!
license udi pid licensepid sn licensesn
!
!
!
redundancy
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 no ip route-cache
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no cdp enable
 no mop enabled
 !
!
interface ISM0/0
 no ip address
 no ip route-cache
 shutdown
 service-module fail-open
 no cdp enable
 !
 hold-queue 60 out
!
interface ISM0/1
 no ip address
 no ip route-cache
 shutdown
 no cdp enable
 !
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 no ip route-cache
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no cdp enable
 !
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
ip nat inside source list 1 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/0
!
access-list 1 permit 10.1.1.0 0.0.0.255
!
!
!
!
!
snmp-server community snmp_lan RO
!
control-plane
 !
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
gatekeeper
 shutdown
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
line aux 0
line 67
 no activation-character
 no exec
 transport preferred none
 transport input all
 transport output pad telnet rlogin lapb-ta mop udptn v120 ssh
 stopbits 1
 flowcontrol software
line vty 0 4
 password password
 login
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
no process cpu extended
no process cpu autoprofile hog
end
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Tried specifying outbound rules by adding

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip access-group lan_out out
!
ip access-list extended la_out
 permit ip any any
```

but to no avail.

After that, also tried utilizing nat pools and route maps, resulting in

```
ip nat pool lan_np 1.2.3.135 1.2.3.135 prefix-length 24
ip nat inside source route-map natmap pool lan_np overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/0 permanent
!
ip access-list extended lan_out
 permit ip any any
!
access-list 101 permit ip 10.1.1.0 0.0.0.255 any
!
!
!
!
route-map natmap permit 10
 match ip address lan_out
```

Both with and without any combination of `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0` and either `interface GigabitEthernet0/0` or the ISP default gateway IP. Results in an `sh ip nat st` of

```
offblast_odin#sh ip nat st
Total active translations: 0 (0 static, 0 dynamic; 0 extended)
Peak translations: 0, occurred 02:58:27 ago
Outside interfaces:
  GigabitEthernet0/0
Inside interfaces:
  GigabitEthernet0/1
Hits: 0  Misses: 0
CEF Translated packets: 0, CEF Punted packets: 0
Expired translations: 0
Dynamic mappings:
-- Inside Source
[Id: 2] route-map natmap pool offblast_lan_np refcount 0
 pool offblast_lan_np: netmask 255.255.255.0
        start 1.2.3.135 end 1.2.3.135
        type generic, total addresses 1, allocated 0 (0%), misses 0
Appl doors: 0
Normal doors: 0
Queued Packets: 0
```

Sadly, nothing so far worked.
[Full final configuration](http://pastebin.com/2zKeTzdM).

Comment: Figures, I used the wrong site. Oh well. :/

Comment: From what are you testing this? Host on lan with this router as its default route?

Comment: Yes, the PC is connected to GigabitEthernet0/1 with 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.12
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.1, with all other interfaces (on the PC) disabled.

Comment: There seem to be a typo in the access-list, "la_out", was this only when you pasted or did you actually enter it incorrectly on the router?

Comment: Also, can you try pinging from the internal address of the router directly? 'ping ip 8.8.8.8 source 10.1.1.1'

Comment: This is IOS 15.0. What is the licensing you have on the router? Using Base IOS or advancedIP? I think if using base IOS, it may not work with Nat, Vpn, etc.
Also have you tried configuring a Static IP on your gig0/0, instead of DHCP from ISP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show output of 'sh ip nat stat' and 'sh ip nat tran'?

I think the config looks correct, did you try applying an ACL on the outside interface to specifically allow the traffic?

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip access-group OUTBOUND out
!
ip access-list extended OUTBOUND
 permit ip any any
```

here's a working example from a 1800 series:

```
interface FastEthernet0
 description $FW_OUTSIDE$
 bandwidth 34000
 ip address 1.2.3.141 255.255.255.240
 ip access-group OUTBOUND out
 ip verify unicast reverse-path
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 load-interval 60
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet1
 description $FW_INSIDE$
 bandwidth 34000
 ip address 192.168.0.254 255.255.255.0
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 load-interval 60
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
ip nat pool GLOBAL_IP_POOL 1.2.3.139 1.2.3.141 prefix-length 24
ip nat inside source route-map natmap pool GLOBAL_IP_POOL overload
!
ip access-list extended natrules
 deny   ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 10.180.3.0 0.0.0.255
 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255 any
!
route-map natmap permit 10
 match ip address natrules
```

Hope this helps.

**Edited:**

I cannot spot anything weird with your config. Since you seem not to have any hits in translation tables at all, there must be a problem either on the connectivity or configuration on the client, or simply an access-list that denies the traffic.

Can you:

1) ping from the router, make sure you do it from the correct interface by entering:

> ping 8.8.8.8 source 10.1.1.1

2) show access-lists

> show access-lists

I set up three routers in a lab and configured rip + nat, and it works just as it is.
[The router in question](http://pastebin.com/eQyempV9) and [the remote router](http://pastebin.com/3ieFSXhu) that specifically denies the internal network of 'the router in question'.

Comment: tran is completely empty, stat has everything at 0, NAT doesn't even activate.
I will try the outbound rule suggestion, thank you.

Comment: I've updated the OP with the attempts, but the router still refuses to even acknowledge the existence of NAT. :/

Comment: It appears that routing was actually what was wrong. I was playing with rip a bit and it seems one of them activated the routing to proceed as normal. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Since this question has now gotten over 1000 views (*whoah*), I will post the accurate answer:
from what I was told later (after using some of the configs posted by @3molo), the line

```
no ip routing
```

was at fault for NAT not working correctly (in hindsight, pretty obvious).